# How to launch a large ec2 instance with ebs ami?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I know I must be missing something crucial, but I am trying to launch an AMI (ami-967edcff) which is an EBS paravirtual AMI and launch it as a "medium or large" instance.  The chief thing I noticed when trying to do that, is that all the large and medium instances are all "instance store" types.  I wish I could post a screen shot of what I'm talking about.

Anyways, when I go to launch, for example, instance type of "m3.large".  It fails with:

```
The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=5hoheke3dcdw953i7sq087tpb for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.
```

I am launching this in N. Virginia, and I just don't know what else it wants from me...

Note: I can launch it as a "t1.micro" no problem.   "t1.micro" is "EBS only".  Anyone know why I can't launch ami-967edcff in a m3.large?

EDIT: Seems like it was just a bug in AWS.  It wasn't showing me the option for "m1.medium" only "m3.medium" and my ebs ami cannot run on any "m3" instances.  If anyone would care to elaborate on what went wrong, please feel free to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is some association with Type of AMI(hvm or paravirtual) and the OS(linux or Windows) and the type of instance that you launch.

Often the HVM is preferred over paravirtual AMI though linux is preferred on both the virtual hardwares.

You can refer market place for an alternative AMI for the same OS, and if not a preference , launch it with HVM virtual type AMI's.

Reference for HVM/PV

[Virtualization Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html)

Comment: are you saying only HVM will work on medium or large instance type?  That doesn't sound right.  Also, when I try to create a linux HVM AMI with packer, I get an error saying Linux hosts are not supported yet.